# Transform data for plotting a stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset of a survey that consists of 23 question items (column 39-62). Each item can have values form 1 to 5 or NA:

```
  39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62
1  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  4  4  4  5  4  4  4  4  5  4  4  4  5  5 NA  4
2  5  3  5  4  4  4  3  5  5  4 NA  5  4  5  3  5  3 NA  4  4  5  3  3  4
3  5  5  5  4  5  4  4  5  5  5  2  5  4  4  4  5  4  3  4  4  5  2  4  4
4  5  4  4  5  5  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  4  3  4  4  5  4  4  4  5  4  3  3
5  5  4  4  5  5  4  4  5  5  4 NA  4  3  2 NA  4  5  2 NA  4  5  3  3  4
6  4  2  4  3  5  4  4  5  4  3  2  3  3  4  4  5  4  3  4  2  4  3  3  4
```

In order plot this data in a stacked bar chart with ggplot2 I need to transform the data in format where the number of occurrences for each answers is listed per item:

```
  39  40  41  ...
1  0   1   6
2  1   2  10
3  1   0  30 
4  2   5   1
5  4  34   1
NA 3   9   3
```

By using count I got the frequency of each column, e.g. `count(df[,1], vars = 1)` returns:

```
  x freq
1  2    1
2  3    4
3  4   18
4  5   32
5 NA    2
```

Because some values do not occur in certain columns the resulting data frames have a different number of rows. Therefore, it is not possible to merged them into the requested matrix format. How can I count the occurrences for each row and put the results in the desired format for a stacked bar chart? Maybe there is much simpler way to plot a stacked bar chart form the original data.

Comment: `sapply(dat, function(x) table(factor(x,levels=1:5), useNA="always") )`

Comment: Thanks  @thelatemail, your solution was the one I was looking for. Great!